# Implementation restriction: EntitySubscription only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most 1000

Tags: apex, managed-package, namespace

I incorporated [Andrew Fawcett's amazing enterprise patterns](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-apex-enterprise-patterns) (code here on GitHub) into my managed extension package (Namespace MY_PACKAGE_NS). In one of my CustomObjects after insert triggers I need to pass the triggering objects to the base package (Namespace BASE_PACKAGE_NS) to let it also do its magic.

I do this inside a [SObjectDomain class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-apex-enterprise-patterns/blob/master/df12/src/classes/SObjectDomain.cls):

```
public with sharing class CustomObjects extends SObjectDomain { 

   public CustomObjects(List<CustomObject__c> sObjectList) {
      super(sObjectList);
   }

   public override void onAfterInsert() {
      BASE_PACKAGE_NS.SObject_TriggerHandler.afterInsert(this.records);         
   }
}
```

Whenever I insert a new record of this type I receive this really strange exception.

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MY_PACKAGE_NS.CustomObjects: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, BASE_PACKAGE_NS.Member: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a09d000000DrG5GAAV; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, BASE_PACKAGE_NS.Member: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: EntitySubscription only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most 1000

(BASE_PACKAGE_NS)
: []

(BASE_PACKAGE_NS)
: []

(BASE_PACKAGE_NS)
Class.MY_PACKAGE_NS.CustomObjects.onAfterInsert: line 14, column 1
Class.MY_PACKAGE_NS.SObjectDomain.handleAfterInsert: line 129, column 1
Class.MY_PACKAGE_NS.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 208, column 1
Class.MY_PACKAGE_NS.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 185, column 1
Trigger.MY_PACKAGE_NS.CustomObjects: line 2, column 1: []
```

This is how my trigger looks

```
trigger CustomObjects on CustomObject__c (after delete, after insert, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    SObjectDomain.triggerHandler(CustomObjects.class);
}
```

It works when I switch back to my old trigger code that not uses extra domain classes:

```
trigger CustomObjects on CustomObject__c (before insert, after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if(Trigger.isInsert) {

        if(Trigger.isAfter) {
            BASE_PACKAGE_NS.SObject_TriggerHandler.beforeInsert(trigger.new);
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, this really seems to complicate things.  I find it's a lot simpler just to have one trigger per object per operation (ie. CustomObject_AfterUpdate, CustomObject_AfterDelete, etc.).  It's just a lot easier on the brain.

Comment: @Ralph Its generally recognised good practice to have one trigger (or domain class in this case) per object, this is what the trigger aspect of the pattern follows. http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/04/apex-trigger-tip-using-a-class-per-object-to-control-logic.html

Comment: @AndrewFawcett totally true, there is a blog article, but the real best practice is make your triggers deterministic in order of execution and don't clutter them with business logic.  The one trigger design definitely does that and it's better than the other trigger handler design i've seen which seem seriously over-engineered.  But so does one trigger per object per operation. Also, wouldn't you love to not have a ton of nested if statements?  Wouldn't you love being able to quickly see exactly what's happen for just the operation you care about?

Comment: @Ralph Ha yes, I really dont like the nested if look as well, do take a look at the Domain layer pattern, it's a OOP way of looking at triggers and behaviour around your objects, without an if statement in sight. :)

Comment: @Andrew Very much looking forward to giving it a thorough look over, thanks for documenting how you'd approached it for the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the error message at line 14 of CustomObjects.onAfterInsert() you're doing a query of EntitySubscription without a limit.  You'll need to put a limit of at least 1000 on it.

You're only getting the error message when the method is called via the SObjectDomain class because it has a "with sharing" directive.  As @ca_petersen pointed out in the comments, queries on Entity Subscription can be quite resource intensive when sharing calculations are involved, henced the increase limit requirement for those queries.

Comment: Indeed! The code i call in my trigger indeed does that.

Comment: But this still doesn't explain why this only happens when I use the SObjectDomain class from the pattern github...

Comment: I'd assume that's probably to do with the "with sharing" directive.  Otherwise your code is running in system context and may not have the same restriction.

Comment: Great! That helped.

Comment: It is due to with sharing. Queries on EntitySubscription that consider sharing are very resource intensive so the platform limits them. Without sharing (or view all data) doesn't have the same limits.

Comment: Thanks @ca_peterson, that explanation regarding with sharing/without sharing really helped.